# Py2app can't read files

Tags: python, py2app

I want to read from a file with a python application. Here is my source code.

`MyApplication.py`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fin = open("/absolute/path/to/file.txt", "r")
    fin.readline()
    fin.close()
```

`setup.py`:

```py
# Copied and pasted it from their docs
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    app=["MyApplication.py"],
setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

Then I try to run `python setup.py py2app` and everything goes smoothly, however when I open the app a popup appears saying "MyApplication Error".
Is there a way for me to solve this or at least get more information about what's happening?

---

EDIT FOR MORE CLARITY:

The line that is causing problems is `fin.readline()`. Also, writing to files works, and reading a file that the app itself has created doesn't generate errors. This code, for example, works.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fout = open("/absolute/path/to/newfile.txt", "a+")
    fout.write("Test\n")
    fout.close()
    fin = open("/absolute/path/to/newfile.txt", "r")
    line = fin.readline()
    fin.close()
    fout = open("/absolute/path/to/newfile.txt", "a+")
    fout.write("Line read: " + line)
    fout.close()
```

The output file will show:

```
Test
Line read: Test
```

Comment: Please provide the complete error message, including any stack trace, in your question.

Comment: @Steve There is no error message, that's literally all that pops up. "MyApplication Error" and the two options are "Open Console" and "Terminate". "Open Console" just generates a bunch of unrelated stuff.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I can't think of anything else to offer.  It sounds like the app isn't running at all.  If I wasn't sure of that, I think my next step would be to put something at the beginning of my code that told me for sure that the app isn't running.  But maybe you already know that.  I'm not familiar with `setuptools`.  I never build packages.  I just run the scripts by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I found this hint veeery useful:

> “right click -> Show Packages -> Resources -> Mac OS”, and execute your app directly do help, because it shows specific errors on the console

Source: http://uxcrepe.com

It might help you a lot, as it shows you typical python errors you are already familiar with!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It was the encoding, because of course it was. Just open the file like this.

```py
fin = open("/absolute/path/to/file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```